# Java HashMap, HashSet, EntrySet relationships in implementation

Tags: java, hashmap

`HashMap` in java has a function `entrySet()` that returns `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>`

> The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in
>   the set, and vice-versa

Based on the doc, I would think that at creation time of `HashMap`, a `HashSet` is being created, and it is updated when any operation is performed on `HashMap`.

But, I also know that the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#102) of `HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap` where keys are unique and values are the same singleton.

1. So `EntrySet` must not be created in the constructor of `HashMap`, it needs to be lazy? If not, `new HashMap()` invokes `new HashSet()` which again invokes `new HashMap()` until the heap explodes.
2. It feels like the `EntrySet` can use`EntrySet.Key.hashCode()` and `EntrySet.Key.equals()` for hash operations, which implies that the `HashMap` in `EntrySet`'s implementation looks very similar to the actual `HashMap`, except that the key is of different type `K` vs `Map.Entry<K,V>`. Then why are we keeping two similar copies? can we just use the `EntrySet` (one `HashMap`)?

Comment: The set returned by `HashMap.entrySet()` is just a light-weight implementation of the `Set` interface. It exposes a `Set` view of the `HashMap` data structure - it's stateless. Have a look at [the source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) (about line 1000).

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark the answer as accepted by checking its green check mark next to the votes.

Answer (score 1):

> Based on the doc, I would think that at creation time of `HashMap`, a `HashSet` is being created, and it is updated when any operation is performed on `HashMap`.

The doc doesn't imply anything like that. It just specifies the behavior of the set.

`EntrySet` is

- cached: the map keeps an instance of it in memory, and when it is requested for the first time it is created (and returned). From there, any request for it just returns it.
- a *proxy* (or *delegator*): `EntrySet` is an inner class (non-static) and as such it is associated with its containing class - the `HashMap`. When it is returned, any operations on it are delegated to the map, a la `entrySet.remove(o) { HashMap.this.remove(o); }`.
- a *representation* (or *view*) of the map. A map can be represented in several ways. For example, you can represent the map as 2 lists (of same length) of keys and values. `EntrySet` represents it as a single list of pairs. Since a map is similar to a matrix structure, you can think about viewing it as a list of rows or a list of columns.

> So `EntrySet` must not be created in the constructor of `HashMap`, it needs to be lazy?

It can be created at the construction of `HashMap` but at that point it's empty, so there's not much point. There's also no guarantee that it will be needed, so no reason to create it.

> If not, `new HashMap()` invokes `new HashSet()` which again invokes new `HashMap()` until the heap explodes.

`HashSet` is not involved. Both `EntrySet` and `HashSet` are direct subclasses of `AbstractSet`. In any case, why would the set constructor invoke a map constructor?

> It feels like the `EntrySet` can use `EntrySet.Key.hashCode()` and `EntrySet.Key.equals()` for hash operations...

`EntrySet` does not need to hash anything itself, it uses the `HashMap`'s `hash()` method.

> ... which implies that the `HashMap` in `EntrySet`'s implementation looks very similar to the actual `HashMap`...

`EntrySet`'s implementation does not keep a copy of the `HashMap`, it is associated with it by virtue of being an inner class of it.

> ... except that the key is of different type `K` vs `Map.Entry<K,V>`.

The type of the key in the `EntrySet<K, V>` is the same as the one in `HashMap<K, V>`.

> Then why are we keeping two similar copies? can we just use the `EntrySet` (one `HashMap`)?

See above, there are no copies.

I refer you to the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.EntrySet) of `EntrySet`, but it would be easier for you to inspect it in your IDE.

Comment: thanks, a small comment, you said "why would the set constructor invoke a map constructor?" It is in the  [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#102) of `HashSet` and the reason is (as I mentioned above) `HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap` where values are the same singleton

Comment: @watashiSHUN I understand what you meant now, but in that case `HashSet` holds a `HashMap` as an implementation detail which you have no access to, so there would be no way to ask the map for an entry set. It will be the same situation, only reversed.